# Trying to understand the Whitney Embedding Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to understand the Whitney Embedding Theorem. 
It says that any $n$-manifold that is closed and smooth can be embedded as a smooth $n$-submanifold of $R^{2n}$.

Take a complicated looking knot in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Clearly it is a $1$-manifold that is smooth and closed. Is it obvious that it can be embedded as a closed $1$-submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^2$?
I am trying to imagine it, but cannot seem to find an embedding.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up the imbedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and its implication on the topology of the complement with the manifold itself. A smooth closed $1$-manifold can always be diffeomorphically mapped onto the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

You will not be able to recover it's embedding into three space from this (the knot), but that's not what Whitneys theorem is about.

Comment: @Thomas- Can you provide a reference for the fact that a smooth closed curve can be diffeomorphically mapped onto the unit circle in $\Bbb{R}^2$? I thought this would be true only for smooth non self-intersecting curves in the plane (Jordan curves).

Comment: @fierydemon it seems to me that you are, again, mixing up the curve in the ambient space with the abstract manifold. The curve, which is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$, is just the image of a diffeomorphism $\phi: S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ onto it's image. The claim in Whitneys theorem is not about $\phi(S^1)$ but about $S^1$ (which is, up to diffeormorphism, the only closed smooth $1$-manfold). And I'm sure you will find an embedding from $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ yourself. If you need a reference have a look at Hirsch's differential topology. This not so much a differential geometry topic.

Comment: @fierydemon my wording may have been inappropriate. I now used 'smooth closed $1$-manifold, which is more accurate here.